# Back_inserter or push_back

Tags: c++

Just a quick question - Which is better to use to add a string to the end of a `vector<string>`, `back_inserter` or `push_back`? mainly, which works faster(I'm working with a huge data, so the marginal difference is actually important) and what are the main differences?

Comment: why not profile it by yourself?

Comment: Time both versions and see for yourself.

Comment: They are not comparable :D

Comment: `back_inserter` is just a function template that constructs a `back_insert_iterator` for a qualified collection based on its type, and is generally used for iteration algorithms to populate a collection. The resulting iterator invokes `push_back()` when inserting elements, but the two (`back_inserter(col)` and `coll.push_back()`) are not equivalent in either type or function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two are not equivalent. You use `std::back_inserter` for example when you need to pass an input iterator to an algorithm. `std::vector<std::string>::push_back` would not be an option in this case. For example

```
std::vector<std::string> a(100, "Hello, World");
std::vector<std::string> b;
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b));
```